# Running remote desktop apps in android emulator

Tags: android, remote-desktop

What would happen if you ran a remote desktop app in the android emulator? Would it just not work?

Comment: i don't have acess to the apps, just thought it would be cool

Comment: I don't think this question fits on SO, but given your name and the style of this question, as a learning exercise think abou this: If it were to "just not work", why would it not work?  What about Android would prohibit it from working?  Could you take a program running on your desktop and drop it into an emulator? Or would you need to write your own in order to get it to work? Or, further yet, is there something about Android that would prevent that type of app from working at all?

Comment: @ChrisThompson It wouldn't work because you would be controlling the computer that you are trying to control the app in.... i feel like i'm in elementary school:P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try http://www.xtralogic.com/rdp_client_download.shtml :D i have not tried it :D

Comment: Thx for the download, i'll post back when i try it